# Use a combined formula to return the value of a cell

Tags: excel

I am trying to obtain the value of a cell that is in a different sheet, from a formula that returns the value of the row where it finds a match.

Basically, what I'm trying to imitate is:

```
=Sheet!Column Row
```

But as follows

```
=Sheet!Column Formula (Which returns the row that meets the conditions of the formula)
```

The problem is that I tried concatenating the name of the sheet, the column and the result of the formula (row), which works, since I get, for example:

```
=Risks!K3
```

But that's all, I get a kind of string and in reality I would need that result to also be calculated by excel and return, precisely, the value of cell K3.

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: `=INDEX(Risks!K:K,formulathatreturns3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `INDEX`:

```
=INDEX(Risks!K:K,formulathatreturns3)
```